# Defining base class `operator==` in terms of derived class `operator==` in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a type hierarchy:

```
struct B { ... };

struct D1 : B { ... };
struct D2 : B { ... };
...
struct Dn : B { ... };
```

Each Di has its own `operator==` defined:

```
struct Di : B
{
    bool operator==(const Di&) const { ... }
    ...
};
```

I now want to define the B `operator==` such that:

```
struct B
{
    bool operator==(const B& that) const
    {
        // psuedo-code
        let i, such the dynamic type of this is Di
        let j, such the dynamic type of that is Dj

        if (i != j)
            return false;
        else
            return Di::operator==(this, that);
    }
 }
```

What is the best way to organize this or write this?

(The end goal is that I want to use the standard container types with a value type of B* (eg `std::set<B*>`), but for it to use the custom `Di::operator==s` when they are from the same derived class)

Comment: have you tried make the operator virtual ?

Comment: As an aside the `std` associative containers use an *ordering* relation like `std::less` not *equality*. See [C++ ordering](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/introducing-c-order-relations/240146592) for requirements on any specialization of `operator<`/`operator>` you provide.

Comment: `operator==` should not be a member function, it should be an external function.

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced: Some do yes, others use other things, for example `std::unordered_set` uses equality and a hash function.  The point of the question is specifically the architecture for equality.

Comment: for symmetry reasons mainly. If you want to let an user compare an object of class A to a non-A object then making it a member function is clumsy: if the other object is not a POD, then accessing the private members of B will be tricky (make A be a friend of B maybe?), plus you will need another function anyway: `operator==(constB&, const A&)` so you will have the same code in 2 different headers. If the object is a POD (say, a `short`) then you will need to write `operator==(short, constA&)` somewhere else, making it hard to maintain.

Comment: @qdii: But in this case we only want to compare objects derived from a common base class, I don't think your rationale applies.

Comment: Don't forget to make the hashing virtual as well, then. It's unfortunate that `unordered_set` separates the equality relation and the hash function: they are to be used as one, because the hash function must match the equality relation (i.e. x == y => h(y) == h(y)).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yes, and as no Di can ever be equal to a Dj, it is sufficient to have the hash function as a pure virtual function in B, and then overridden in each Di without respect to other Dj's hash functions. (ie collisions between Di::hash and Dj::hash dont matter)

Answer (score 6):

Define a protected virtual function in the base class. Make it pure virtual to ensure that each subclass `Di` provides an implementation. The function will know the target of the cast, because it belongs to a `Di`. Call that function from the operator `==` in the base class, and let it perform the comparison, like this:

```
struct B {
    bool operator==(const B& that) const {
        return this->equals(that);
    }
protected:
    virtual bool equals(const B& other) const=0;
};
struct D1 {
protected:
    virtual bool equals(const B& other) const {
        D1 *that = dynamic_cast<D1*>(&other);
        if (!that) return false;
        // Perform D1-specific comparison here.
        // You can use the == operator of D1, but you do not have to:
        return (*this) == (*that);
    }
};
```

The effect of this construct is making the implementation of the `==` operator virtual.

Comment: This double dispatch looks like a candidate for the `Visitor` pattern.

Comment: @PeterWood Double-dispatch with or without the visitor would be an overkill here. If comparing `Di` and `Dj` was required to return anything but `false` at least in some situations, a double dispatch would be warranted. However, OP wants all cross-type comparisons to return `false`, hence I think that this simplified solution would work well.

Comment: I think you shouldn't make the base class equals pure virtual:
`virtual bool equals(const B& other) const { return false; }`
as otherwise you might get weird errors when D1 is compared to D2.

Comment: @Alex I don't think it's going to be a problem, because the equality check will be done either by `D1` or `D2`, not by `B`, so an implementation of `equals` would be available. Comparing an instance of `B` to anything would be problematic, but it does not look like the OP allows creating instances of `B` in the first place.

Comment: What is the point of creating a separate equals function?  Why not make `operator==` virtual directly? [demo](http://ideone.com/Umy7aL)

Comment: @user1131467 Because the overridden `operator==` will accept `const D&`, not `const B&`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How would you avoid code duplication for `equals` in all `Di` classes? It would be the same if the call is merely dispatched to `operator==`.

Comment: @user1131467 having a non public virtual function and a public nonvirtual function calling the other one allows you to do some common work before dispatching to class specific stuff (i.e.: it would be possible to check if the address is equal and only if they aren't call the virtual function)
Mikhail: if you want syntax duplication removed one could use CRTP to inherit the operator== with the baseclass name.

Comment: @user1131467 Making `==` virtual directly may also work if the implementation is the same as in my example (i.e. the operator calls the function, and does nothing else). You have a little more control with a non-virtual operator calling a virtual function, but your solution may be more appropriate in the context of your design.

Comment: Would it correct to add `override` to the function signatures in the derived classes?

Comment: @soandos In C# - yes; in C++ - no.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight variation of [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792425/1137388) with added features (e.g. less code duplication)

```
#include <typeinfo> // for typeid

struct B {

  bool operator==(const B& that) const {

    if (this == &that) // trivially equal
      return true;

    if (typeid(*this) != typeid(that)) // trivially different
      return false;

    return equals(that); // delegates to the virtual function
  }

  // polymorphic classes must have virtual destructors
  virtual ~B() = default;

protected:

  virtual bool equals(const B& that) const = 0;

};

struct D1 : B {

  bool operator ==(const D1& that) const {
    // ...
  }

private:

  // private because this function is not meant to be called except through
  // B::equals
  bool equals(const B& that) const override {
    // static_cast is safe here because execution only gets here if the
    // dynamic type of that is D1 (this was tested in B::operator =()
    return *this == static_cast<const D1&>(that);
  }

};
```